# Undefined property y call to a member function on null en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

estoy realizando un proyecto con php y codeigniter pero me sale error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mis codigos son los siguientes:

database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'sedeges',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

vista
vista_centroAcogidonuevo.php

```
    <html>
<body>
    <h1>Registrar nuevo centro de acogida</h1>
    <form action="centroAcogido/datos" method="POST">
        <label>Nombre del Centro :</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="ingresar el nombre del centro" size="40" name="nombre" id="nombre" /><p>
        <label>Nombre del Administrador :</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="nombre del administrador" size="40" name="nomb_admin" id="nomb_admin" /><p>
        <label>Direccion del centro :</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="ingresar la direccion del centro" size="40" name="direccion" id="direccion" /><p>
        <label>Telefono :</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="ingresar el numero de telefono" size="40" name="telefono" id="telefono" /><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar Registro"/>

    </form>

</body>
<html/>
```

controlador
centroAcogido.php

```
   <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class centroAcogido extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();

                // Your own constructor code
        }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('centroAcogida/vista_centroAcogido_nuevo');
    }

    function datos()
    {
        $data=$arrayName = array('nombre' =>$this ->input ->post ('nombre'), 
                                  'administrador ' =>$this ->input ->post('nomb_admin'),
                                  'direccion' =>$this ->input ->post('direccion'),
                                  'telefono' =>$this ->input ->post('telefono')
            );
        $this->load->model('M_centroAcogido');//caraga el modelo
        $this->M_centroAcogido->crearCentro($data);//funcion crear centro (va con los valores introducidos a data)
    }
}
```

modelo
M_centroAcogido.php

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_centroAcogido extends CI_Model {



        public function __construct()
        {
                // Call the CI_Model constructor
                parent::__construct();
        }

        function crearCentro($data)
        {
            $this->db->insert('centro_acogida', array('nombre_centro'=>$data['nombre'], 
                                                    'admin_centro'=>$data['administrador'],
                                                        'dir_centro'=>$data['direccion'],
                                                        'telefono_centro'=>$data['telefono']));

        }

 }
```

es primera vez que uso codeigniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores:

El formato para los controladores es: los nombres del controlador siempre deben ir con la primera letra en mayúscula en tu caso `centroAcogido` debería ser `CentroAcogido` y el nombre del archivo php debe ser igual, debería estar `CentroAcogido.php`

Luego en tu modelo, a menos que cargues la base de datos automáticamente en tu archivo config.php, deberías cargar la db en tu modelo así:

```
public function __construct(){
  // Call the CI_Model constructor
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->database();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda